# Save json(content is japanese) in database

Tags: json

I used laravel to save json in to database like as the folowing format
[{"s":"0.000","e":"","t":"\u672c\u65e5\u306f\u3054\u6765\u5854\u304f\u3060\u3055\u3044\u307e\u3057\u3066"},{"s":"0.001","e":"28.000","t":""},{"s":"0.002","e":"29.000","t":"\u3069\u3046\u305e\u6771\u4eac\u306e\u4eca\u3092\u3054\u3086\u3063\u304f\u308a\u304a\u697d\u3057\u307f\u304f\u3060\u3055\u3044\u307e\u305b\u30022"}]
Japanese become "\u3069\u3046\u305e\u..." 
Can you tell me the way to covert them to Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

`"\u672c\u65e5\u306f\u3054\u6765\u5854\u304f\u3060\u3055\u3044\u307e\u3057\u3066"` represents the same string as `"本日はご来塔くださいまして"`. It just depends on the JSON stringifier whether or not it escapes certain characters. Since you're using laravel, I'm assuming you are generating the JSON in PHP. If you are using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option to get JSON with the Japanese UTF-8 characters instead of the escape sequences.

Either way when you parse the JSON you will get the same string. When you display that sting make sure you interpret it as UTF-8.